# Painting one part of my model causes another part to get painted as well

Tags: texture-painting

I have a problem here.
When i'm painting the foot of my character, the blur that appears on the foot is, somehow, mirrored on the leg too, and the same thing happens when i try the inverse. I didn't use any mirror property while working on the model, and none of axes symmetry is active.

What could possibly be causing this?

[image]

Comment: first thought: the vertices use the same uv texture coordinates, but I guess you unwrapped your character correctly and there is nothing overlapping that ain't supposed to

Comment: Well, I hadn't yet unwrapped the model. But now that you mentioned it, the problem is no longer a problem.
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I believe TARDIS Maker is correct in your UV it appears that the painted parts do overlap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im almost positive that some kind of mirror is applied automatically; it can be found on that texture paint panel, it may be collapsed in a menu, probably labeled 'Mirror' or something like that, but if not, it will have 3 or 4 options; one being x-axis, one being y-axis, and so on. At least one of them should be checked, un-check it, and it and i believe your problems are over.

Comment: This is almost certainly an overlap of the vertices in the UV Map.

Comment: Welcome to SE! That is indeed a valid option, however once you have enough reputation, posts like this might be better suited as comments. You could also expand this post to contain some more detail and maybe even screenshots to make it easier to follow what you are saying.